# Linked Excel chart in PPT (update issues)

Tags: excel, powerpoint

i have some Data output (output.xlsx with multiple sheets). i need these informations in Powerpoint-slides as a chart. 
so i create the chart in Powerpoint(insert chart -> edit Data in excel (new excel window opened) -> create a link to the output.xlsx (=[output.xlsx]Sheet1'A1 )

next month i get a new output.xlsx (same format but new values). i save the new output.xlsx in the same folder like the last one (overwrite). then i open the powerpoint slides but i get no question to update the links.

on the "File" tab in powerpoint there is no information of the linked excel sheet. 
to update the values i need to click into the chart -> edit data -> (excel window opens) ->data -> edit links -> update values

so the chart remembers the link only in the excel version of powerpoint but not in Powerpoint itself. 
i have 25 charts in this slides so it would be great if anyone knows how to update all charts at once.

any ideas :)?

best regards

Comment: Does the data change when you select the chart and press `Refresh Data` in the Design Tab?

Comment: i cannot click on Refresh Data (its grey), i can only click on "edit data" and "select data".

Answer (score 0):

Right now you do the following:

1. create chart in PowerPoint, which creates Excel embedded in your presentation
2. you link that Excel to the Excel with the data

I suggest skipping the intermediary and link the data directly to your Excel

1. Create chart in your Excel with data
2. Cut it and Paste in PowerPoint

Now when you edit the data you open the original file, and can use the Refresh button in the Design tab

**EDIT** the point about editing the data was just to visualize that the data is linked to the source directly. After the chart is in PowerPoint it doesn't have to be created anymore, just refreshed. It's a one time setup

Comment: not possible for me. i cannot save the charts in the output.xlsx because its every month a new file (only data) its an export from a BI-Tool.

Comment: you don't save them in Excel, you just create them in Excel so that they link directly to your data. Then you cut them from Excel and paste in the PowerPoint, where they should be. You do it once and then can use refresh in PowerPoint to get the updated data

Comment: so i need a second xlsx template file where i link all the data and build the charts in this second template? thats  a lot of work but i think you found the solution ;) thank you

Comment: no, just use your current output.xlsx. In PowerPoint chart will remember reference to something like `C:\Excelfiles\output.xlsx!Sheet1'A1`, so when you replace the excel file with new one (with the same name), the reference will get the data from the new file (in the old path)

Comment: i cannot create charts in output.xlsx  ...because so i have to do this every month. next month there is a new output.xlsx without charts and new values.

Comment: that's fine. just try the following to test: 1.create chart in output.xlsx 2.cut it and paste in PowerPoint 3.close the output.xlsx WITHOUT SAVING. 4 replace output.xlsx with new/old version 5.refresh chart in PowerPoint to see the data change. Next month you will just need to do steps 4&5

Comment: i tested it and the chart disapears and i see the Table grid of the chart. (powerpoint  sill remember the link but cant find the chart) but with the second xlsx template it works so i'm happy ;) thank you for your help!

Comment: I still think you can simplify it if you follow the procedure here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-a-linked-Excel-chart-in-PowerPoint-692497a5-c7de-4486-a435-5af1eff02821

Comment: i already fail at point 1 of this procedure. i dont have a workbook with a chart. i just have a workbook with a table. when i add a chart to this workbook i can not save it because i get a new file next month. its not the file with new values its every month a brand new file with just a table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206439/discussion-between-stachu-and-7660).